# How to write a search function in Django

Tags: django

In my project I have to create a Search function. With this function it should be possible to search for a name in my customers. Do you know a tutorial or something for my problem?

Comment: customers is part of the DB model?

Comment: @zero323: haystack is probably overkill here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm, that has to be a very difficult problem, since obviously you couldn't come with at least the beginning of a solution nor even find anything on Google...

Well, Let's see...

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get("q")
    if q:
       # you may want to use `__istartswith' instead
       results = Customer.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
    else:
       # you may want to return Customer.objects.none() instead
       results = Customer.objects.all()     

    context = dict(results=results, q=q)
    return render(request, "yourapp/search.html", context)
```

Yes, really really really difficult indeed. Err, what about reading the FineManual next time ?

Comment: The cold tone is not appreciated on SO. Please go thru the code of conduct if you need to. Idiot.